# Solace Queue - Message should automatically redeliver on exception without reconnecting session

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, solace-mq

We are planning to use Solace Queue Management. One of the usecase is, After receiving message on consumer, if any exception while processing message, Message should be redeliver automatically.

As of now, I am not sending ack to Queue so message will not removed from Queue but unfortunately it's not able to redeliver automatically. If I restart session then only I am able to receive same message.

I have explore few options ex. session.rollback or session.revoke on exception but it will increased the delivery count of all the messages in the queue. Also there isn't any configuration of delay time to redeliver same message.

The expectation is, same message should be redelivered after 30 min (configured delay) automatically.

Below is sample code I am using for Consumer:

https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-jms/blob/master/src/main/java/com/solace/samples/QueueConsumer.java

```java
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            System.out.printf("TextMessage received: '%s'%n", ((TextMessage) message).getText());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Message received.");
        }
        System.out.printf("Message Content:%n%s%n", SolJmsUtility.dumpMessage(message));

        // ACK the received message manually because of the set SupportedProperty.SOL_CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE above
        message.acknowledge();

        latch.countDown(); // unblock the main thread
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error processing incoming message.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Appreciate your support. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solace doesn't support such feature currently. Messages are not redelivered on the application layer. They will be redelivered only if the connection (flow to be exact) is reestablished.

Solace does redeliver the messages on the transport level. Purpose of this is to ensure that the messages are delivered to the application buffer. From then on, its application's responsibility to process them and ack. Redelivering beyond that point will lead to duplicate messages on the consumer end - which will be in violation of several protocols including JMS.

When the application flow is reestablished, any unacked messages can be safely redelivered since we know the original flow it was delivered to can no longer ack the message (and lead to potential dup message delivery).